# Tengo problema con el getMenuInflater()

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.victor.asteroids;

import...  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    private Button btnAcercaDe,btnSalir;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        btnAcercaDe=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAcercaDe);  
        btnSalir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalir);  
        btnAcercaDe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                lanzarAcercaDe(null);  
            }  
        });  
        btnSalir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                finish();  
            }    
        });  
    }  

    public void lanzarAcercaDe(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,AcercaDe.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();//Aqui se lanza el error Unreachable Statement
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu,menu);
        return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te das cuenta tienes dos `return`,

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); //primer return.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();//Aqui se lanza el error Unreachable Statement
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu,menu);
        return true; //segundo return.
     }
```

el primero va a provocar que tengas un menú nulo ya que no infla en ningún momento el menú:

```
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Puedes simplemente retornar `true`, después de que el inflater, "infla" el layout mediante el método `inflate()` :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

> **[MenuInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html)** Instancia el .xml del menú en objectos Menu.

Answer (score -1):

Así debe quedar la función `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();   
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu,menu);  
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);  
}
```